# How do I create a message input field similar to Instagram in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter and trying to build a chat app, and I want to create a message input field like the one Instagram has, but I can't seem to figure out how they managed it to float.

[image]

Is there some way you can do that in Flutter?

Comment: Can you include sample snippet that you've tried

Comment: you can search for backdrop filter widget in flutter